# Controlling the size of an image within a CSS Grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid layout with a bunch of areas and a photo container.

I don't know how to:

1. control the size of the photo, so that it is contained within the area of the grid
2. keep the width of the photo at 100% (thus equal to its container) and scale the height of the container to fit the photo. Basically, when the window becomes smaller, the width of the photo becomes smaller, and so does the height - pulling the tag, album, and rotate elements up.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40vh 30vh 30vh;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "info    photo photo photo   photo" 
    "comment photo photo photo   photo" 
    "comment tag     tag   album rotate"
}

.photo {
  grid-area: photo;
  background: yellow;
}

.photo>img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%
}

.info {
  grid-area: info;
  background: pink;
}

.tag {
  grid-area: tag;
  background: teal;
}

.comment {
  grid-area: comment;
  background: green;
}

.album {
  grid-area: album;
  background: red;
}

.rotate {
  grid-area: rotate;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo">
    <img src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="info">info</div>
  <div class="tag">tag</div>
  <div class="comment">comment</div>
  <div class="album">album</div>
  <div class="rotate">rotate</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have two different problems here.

I'll address the first one, which is to contain the image in its container. You almost had it.

*Your code:*

```
.photo > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You just needed to specify a maximum height on the image so it could not overflow the container:

```
.photo > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xq4m62Lq/)

---

The second problem, which is to scale the size of the image container, and drag up the grid items below when the image gets smaller, is significantly more complex.

This isn't an issue relating to the image. In fact, you can remove the image altogether when trying to solve this problem.

This is an issue of dynamically sizing a grid item (the image container). Why would this grid item change size in relation to the image size, when its size is being controlled by `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-rows`?

In addition, why would the bottom row of grid items (`tag`, `album`, `rotate`) follow the image container either up or down? They would have to exit their row.

Scaling the entire grid container wouldn't be a problem. But it seems like you only want to scale one grid item (the image container). It's tricky. You're probably looking at additional containers, `auto` values for lengths, and possibly scripting.

Here's what happens if you give the image rows an `auto` value: [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xq4m62Lq/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. The first problem/solution solved my headache! You are right about the 2nd part. I will solve it be tuning my different layouts for the 3 media layouts I'm working with (mobile, tablet, laptop). I completely get your point :-)

Comment: I can be helpful to add overflow: auto; to .photo, if the image is too tall it will expand outside the parent grid. By telling the parent to use overflow it’ll fix this height issue. This only effects images inside a grid child (grid -> div -> image). If the image is a direct child of the grid it’ll scale fine.

Answer (score 14):

What if you use a **background-image** inside one of the grid cells rather than an IMG tag (haven't used display: grid yet b/c it's so new - cool!)

Then using **background-size** and **background-position**, you can size it properly within that cell.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 40vh 30vh 30vh;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: "info    photo photo photo   photo" "comment photo photo photo   photo" "comment tag     tag   album rotate"
}

.photo {
  grid-area: photo;
  background: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover; /* <-- background size */
  background-position: center; /* <-- background position */
}

.info {
  grid-area: info;
  background: pink;
}

.tag {
  grid-area: tag;
  background: teal;
}

.comment {
  grid-area: comment;
  background: green;
}

.album {
  grid-area: album;
  background: red;
}

.rotate {
  grid-area: rotate;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="photo" style="background-image: url('https://thumbs.web.sapo.io/?epic=YmIzAEUIMb3pue+Zz8qV8QS/WuKmq0vrL/lWiluSn7SstKeeh7/UTTBAuDlhHFD6YC9+vaCHBQuNOXeVaHkjzTSE8tF3hMBev6512ha92Yc4kRw=&W=1200&H=627&crop=center&delay_optim=1')">
  </div>
  <div class="info">info</div>
  <div class="tag">tag</div>
  <div class="comment">comment</div>
  <div class="album">album</div>
  <div class="rotate">rotate</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A few years later and I had to use this method to make sure that my image stayed contained within the grid cell when SCALING UP.  On scaling down, other answer worked, but when scaling up, the image (svg) was actually causing my container to stretch vertically (pushing down), out of it's parent container which already had a height defined on it.  I still can't figure out why the image would scale up and and cause the image container (grid element) to grow height wise even with a height set on the grid parent.

Answer (score 5):

I have a slight correction which works for any combination of aspect ratio of both **css-grid cell** *and* **src img**. (As the accepted solution only works if the aspect ratio of the cell is *greater* than the aspect ratio of the image). It's very simple:

```
.photo > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You probably need to add explicit width: 100% to the image

Comment: I have added that, but it simply makes it fall out at the bottom...I have tried Object-fit - but that does not do anything