# Define the height of Grid not by all columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I created a grid consisting of 3 columns and 4 rows. The last column is completely covered by an image (».box-image«, not as a background image), whereby this image and the column in which it is located should not extend the height of the other columns.

```
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 50px;
}
```

```
.grid .box-image{
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.grid .box-image img{
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How do I determine that .box-image does not increase the height of the grid (1fr 1fr), and only assumes the height determined by the other content?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling the size of an image within a CSS Grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090760/controlling-the-size-of-an-image-within-a-css-grid-layout)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. There is an attempt to make the grid assume the height of the image (100%). I would like the column with the image (.box-image) to assume the height of the remaining columns.

Comment: Please include your HTML preferably as a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You should only need to add a `max-height` to the image. See the 2 examples below which have different row heights. In both cases the image fills the height based on the height of the other rows.

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 25%) 4fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 50px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.grid .box-image {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.grid .box-image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="box-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
  </div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

**With a 1000x1000px image:**

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 25%) 4fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 50px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.grid .box-image {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.grid .box-image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="box-image">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1000">
  </div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

**With no image:**

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 25%) 4fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 50px;
}

.grid > div {
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.grid .box-image {
    grid-column: 3;
    grid-row: 1 / 5;
}

.grid .box-image img {
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div class="box-image"></div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not the point. The height of the image should be insignificant for the overall height of the grid. Let's say in Div 4 and Div 5 are text content, which increases the height of the grid, then the height of the image should also expand. Not the other way around.

Comment: If you look at the 2nd demo you'll see the height of the image adjusts to the grid size. The image is actually 1000x1000px, but it is collapsed to the height of the grid rows.

Comment: But if you delete the picture out of the grid, the height of the boxes (4 - 7) will also be lower.

Comment: Nope, it's the same size. I added another snippet showing the same markup without the image, and you can see the grid is still the same size.

Comment: The height of the grid is defined by the `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr 50px;`, the image adjusts to fill the height of the 4 rows since the image spans all 4 rows.

Comment: Brett, thanks for your help, but the grid has definitely another height with image inside. Please open both code snippet at a new window, you see the grid with the 1000x1000 fills almost a browser window, without not.

Comment: Currently the height of the image is determined by the width. And the height of the picture in turn enlarges the grid.

Comment: Are you talking about in my demo, or in your demo?

Comment: What browser are you viewing these in? We might be dealing with a browser issue here. In Chome, the grids have the same height in the 2 demos above - 'With a 1000x1000px image', and 'With no image'.

Comment: Ah, I see. Safari has an issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770074/css-grid-row-height-safari-bug

Comment: The linked post just discuss the differences between the browsers and helps to get 100% height of the image. But actually there is no conclusion for the problem here.

Comment: So I would very much like to provide a solution to the problem, but unfortunately I have not yet found any.

Comment: It does, under the Solution section. It involves making the item a flex item.

Comment: For me it just generates a solution to view the image with a height of 100%.