# How to have an image fit the height of grid container?

Tags: css

I did try to get a hint from: [Controlling the size of an image within a CSS Grid layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46090760/controlling-the-size-of-an-image-within-a-css-grid-layout)

My code:

```
import { FC } from 'react';

import './style.css';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'grid',
        gridTemplateColumns: '1fr 1fr',
        border: '1px solid red',
        maxHeight: 250,
      }}
    >
      <img
        style={{ width: '100%', maxHeight: '100%', objectFit: 'cover' }}
        src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"
      />
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Result:

[image]

code on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-hy8g2s?file=src%2FApp.tsx

How can I have the image fit the height of the grid container, while taking the full available width (which is half of the container width, like it's currently doing well) ? In case it's not clear, the only change I want is for the height of the image to fit the height of the container. Also, I don't want to use `overflow: hidden`. I want the image height to fit the height of the container while showing the full image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit

Grid sets this annoying property `min-height: max-content` (or something like that) so you need to turn that off with `min-height: 0` for it to fit (and `min-width: 0` if you aren't putting a dog picture in your app):

```
      gridArea: 'span 1',
      objectFit: 'cover',
      minHeight: '0',
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
```

Like this:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3rwrer?file=src%2FApp.tsx

### Old answer

Use `position: absolute`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cpbxvz?file=src%2FApp.tsx

But, it depends what you are trying to do, and its strange you have a CSS grid in two columns, but want to make your image cover both of them.

```
gridColumn: "span 2"
```

Might be closer to what you are aiming for.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-3rwrer?file=src%2FApp.tsx

Comment: I don't want to cover both of them, just half (horizontally), all I want is the height to fit the parent. Will comment in my question, thanks

Comment: I actually just remember the better way of solving it is to set `gridTemplateRows: minmax(0, 1fr)` — this will mean you don't constantly need to start setting every child to have `min-height: 0` — less CSS. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bmysx1?file=src%2FApp.tsx